# Не заносит в MySQL текст

Tags: mysql

```
$status = 555;
echo $status;
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE $db_table SET status = $status WHERE id ='$id'");

// Проверяем, есть ли ошибки
if ($result == 'TRUE') {
    echo "Статус установлен!. <a href='profile.php'>Вернуться</a>";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка! Статус не установлен.";
}
```

Если значение $status = числу, то в бд она заносится, если текст, то нет, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воздержусь от лишних комментариев...

```
//Во-первых:
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE $db_table SET status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($status)."' WHERE id ='$id'");

// Во-вторых:

if ($result) {
    echo "Статус установлен!. <a href='profile.php'>Вернуться</a>";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка! Статус не установлен.";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!:)